# Java error with "exception in thread"

Tags: java

Hey guys I'm currently making a program where it will reverse the input from the user.
Currently my code is

```
import java.util.*;

public class Reverse {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        List<String> input = new ArrayList<>();
        while (in.hasNextLine())
            input.add(in.nextLine());
        for (int x = 0; input.size() >= x; x++) {
            String reverse = "";
            for (int z = input.get(x).length(); z > 0; z--) {
                reverse += input.get(x).charAt(z - 1);
            }

            System.out.println(reverse);
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the error where it says

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
at Reverse.main(Reverse.java:12)*
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: You need to read about length and size of the array. Index of array starts from 0; So when you have 3 elements, they will be indexed 0,1,2; At the same time the size of the array is 3; You error is due to the equalOrGreater comparison. I will recommend reading about the foreach loop which will save you some trouble in the future! Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the bounds of your `for` loop:

```
for (int x=0; x < input.size(); x++) {
    String reverse = "";
    for (int z=input.get(x).length(); z > 0; z--) {
        reverse += input.get(x).charAt(z - 1);
    }

    System.out.println(reverse);
}
```

Accessing a `List` is zero-based, so in your outer loop, for a list of size 3, the greatest value you want for the `x` index is 2.

Answer (score 0):

On last iteraton, "x" is equal to input.size(), so element input.get(x) will not exist, at the second "for" loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
input.size() >= x
```

At the last iteration, x is equal to the size of the list. Since list indices start at 0, this is an invalid index.

The idiomatic way of looping by index in Java is

```
for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
```

You should use this idiomatic way.

But for such a loop, where you don't need the index, you should use a for-each loop:

```
for (String s : input) {
```

This way is safer, guaranteed to be efficient whatever the type of the list is, and is more readable too.

Answer (score 0):

```
    package com.stackwork;

    import java.util.*;

    public class Reverse {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            List<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();
            while (in.hasNextLine())
                input.add(in.nextLine());
// prints the size of array
            System.out.println("the array size :" + input.size());
            for (int x = 0; input.size() > x; x++) {
//Prints the incremented x value at each step 
                System.out.println("the x value inside the for loop :" + x);
                String reverse = "";
                for (int z = input.get(x).length(); z > 0; z--) {
//prints the length of each string in the array
                    System.out.println("the value of z is :" + z);
                    reverse += input.get(x).charAt(z - 1);
//prints the value in each step of reverse
                    System.out.println("each step of reverse " + reverse);
                }

                System.out.println(reverse);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Comments and an explanation would make it even clearer! :)